# How to show content of html file in R?

Tags: html, r

Here's a question I have for an assignment:

> Write R code(s) to read the contents of the provided file COS206ShoppingCart.html into a variable called cart and then show the first 5 lines of cart.

The textbook I was required to get for school, "Learning R" is extremely unclear, and it took me a long while to even figure out this basic stuff I'm about to show you.

First I had to install the package for XML (which is used for HTML also), and download the library:

```
install.packages("XML")

library(XML)
```

I think this is the right way to read the contents of the file into a variable:

```
cart <- htmlTreeParse('COS206ShoppingCart.html')
```

But no matter how much I google, I can't figure out how to show the first 5 lines of the variable `cart`. Or what that even means, since the contents of the file is a 4x5 table.

Any advice? Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your assignment is vague. `cart <- readLines('COS206ShoppingCart.html')[1:5]` fits that criteria

Comment: Would be good to see COS206ShoppingCart.html.

Comment: Thanks @rawr I used what you suggested. I'll just have to wait and see what my professor says.